# Button re sizing on a webpage

Tags: html, css

I programmed a simple html page with some buttons on them that I made large using the html command

```
<input type="button" style="height: 50px; width: 100px" value="button" />
```

This works OK on my win7 / google chrome / IE 8 platform, but when I passed a copy of the html file to a friend with a macbook / safari setup the buttons were not any different from normal html buttons.

I read online that the buttons are rendered more by the OS than by the browser and this probably explains the difference. My question then is being that I do not have a non-windows machine to test on, will the buttons be the same on all platforms if I do the styling in CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour, Andy.

If you set items such as the `border-style` or `background` of a button, you will be overriding the browser's default button styling (which for many browsers, by default, is the host OS style), and so you'll see something like Facebook's or StackOverflow's buttons that are platform independent..

Comment: Then that means that it is not possible to make a button appear the same way across multiple platforms? Is there at least a way to make the button larger across all platforms?

Comment: @Andy: If you change the button's styles, for example changing the border to a solid rectangle, then the button will appear the same in all platforms, since it is using your styles and not its defaults.

Comment: I looked in at w3.org and a few "filler" sites to learn how to do the CSS styling, I think I am picking it up pretty well. I was mostly concerned about having the same thing happen when I use a different platform.